# How to store only 1 part of a REST response in a hash table?

Tags: rest, powershell

Suppose I have the following response from an `Invoke-RestMethod` call:

```
Function Renew_Token($token) {
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("X-Vault-Token", $token)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod  -method POST -uri "https://vault.com:8243/v1/auth/token/renew-self" -ContentType 'application/json' -headers $headers
    $response| ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100
}
Function getValues($token) {
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("X-Vault-Token", $token)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod  -method GET -uri "https://vault.com:8243/v1/secret/vault/development" -ContentType 'application/json' -headers $headers
    $response.data| ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100
}
getValues $token
```

Response output:

```
{
    "request_id":  "ghgdf5-yuhgt886-gfd76trfd",
    "lease_id":  "",
    "renewable":  false,
    "lease_duration":  0,
    "data":  null,
    "wrap_info":  null,
    "warnings":  null,
    "auth":  {
                 "client_token":  "i657ih4rbg68934576y",
                 "accessor":  "t543qyt54y64y654y",
                 "policies":  [
                                  "default",
                                  "vault"
                              ],
                 "token_policies":  [
                                        "default",
                                        "vault"
                                    ],
                 "metadata":  null,
                 "lease_duration":  2000,
                 "renewable":  true,
                 "entity_id":  ""
             }
}
{
    "key1":  "value1",
    "key2":  "value2",
    "key3":  "value3"
}
```

Suppose I store that response in a variable:

```
$response
```

How do I then select only this section of the response:

```
    "key1":  "value1",
    "key2":  "value2",
    "key3":  "value3"
```

to be stored in a hashtable?

```
$HashTable = @{ }
$HashTable.Add($response.key, $response.value)
```

Comment: Working with CyberArk EPV?

Comment: @trebleCode nope, https://www.vaultproject.io/

Comment: Whats the object type you get back? Whats the output of `$response.GetType()`?

Comment: @trebleCode It's going to be `PSCustomObject`.

Comment: @DanielMann beat me to it, but yes, its PSCustomObject

Comment: @trebleCode i get this: IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Comment: @Cataster I copied the response, but based on the bracing this looks like two separate responses. Can you edit?

Comment: @trebleCode yes so basically the first response is returned from another function that renews the token. and the second response is returned from the Function getValues(). You see i am trying to have one script do all the REST calls, and another script that uses those values from the REST call, for easier maintenance purposes (i dont want to have everything in one script). so my ultimate goal is to to do something like this in the other script i am creating: $response = & ".\get_vault_values.ps1. get_vault_values.ps1 is the script that has these Invoke REST functions

Comment: @Cataster I posted an answer, let me know if you need help

Comment: @trebleCode i posted a comment on the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating the object as a PSCustomObject, where key1, key2, and key3 are part of a single response:

```
$response =

[PSCustomObject]@{
    request_id="ghgdf5-yuhgt886-gfd76trfd";
    lease_id=  "";
    renewable= $false;
    lease_duration=  0;
    data=$null;
    wrap_info=$null;
    warnings=$null;
    auth=  
    @{
        client_token=  'i657ih4rbg68934576y';
        accessor=  't543qyt54y64y654y';
        policies=  @('default','vault');
        token_policies=  @('default','vault');
        metadata= $null;
        lease_duration= 2000;
        renewable= $true;
        entity_id=  "";
    }
    key1= 'value1';
    key2= 'value2';
    key3= 'value3';
}
```

Only get the keys that have the string 'key' in the name:

```
$targetKeys = $response.psobject.Properties | ? {$_.Name -match 'key'}
```

Create a new table and add each of the desired keys to it:

```
$newTable = @{}

foreach($key in $targetKeys)
{
    $newTable.Add($key.Name, $key.Value)
}

return $newTable
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                           
key3                           value3                                                                                          
key1                           value1                                                                                          
key2                           value2
```

If the second response only has key1, key2, and key3 in it, you can access the properties directly, so lets say

```
$secondResponse = [PSCustomObject]@{
    key1=  "value1";
    key2=  "value2";
    key3=  "value3";
}
```

You can access like this:

```
$secondResponse.key1
$secondResponse.key2
$secondResponse.key3
```

Comment: first, thank you for providing answer :) so regarding this part: Only get the keys that have the string 'key' in the name....that is not really ideal. i have them named as "key1, key2, etc.." because the actualy names are pretty long/complex so i renamed them like that just for stackoverflow purposes so its easier to read/remember. the actual key names are like "ID_123, Svc_Accnt789, Provider", so you see, i cant use name matching because the keys have various names. i was looking for a property, like $response.key $response.value

Comment: Ah gotcha. If the second response only has those 3 keys, regardless of name, just take out the `| ? {$_.Name -match 'key'}` part and the foreach loop will add all of them, so you dont need to target with some matching criteria